# Problema com importação de CSV para o Mysql

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, csv

Estou importando informações de arquivos csv para o banco do mysql algumas planilhas foram importadas corretamente, porém algumas planilhas ao importar para o banco aparece uma aspas duplas que não existe na planilha assim afetando a posição das informações das colunas estou utilizando o `load data local infile` para importa o arquivo csv.

a linha no banco aparace assim

```
id | material| categoria  |   lote  |   mes   |
1  |   "     |   janeiro  |   null  |  null   |
2  | lápis   |  escolar   |   "5    |   null  |
```

nota que o mês aparece na coluna categoria na planilha esta na coluna mês e o aspas não tem na planilha eu já copiei para uma planilha em branco só com o valores puros e mesmo assim pega essa aspas duplas o load esta normal pois algumas planilhas não deram estes problema o código do load esta abaixo:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/report/uploads/$campo'
                            INTO TABLE reparo.oob
                            character set 'utf8'
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                            IGNORE 1 LINES
                            (@FAMILIA,@BRAND,@QT_LOTE,@QT_AMOSTRA,@MAQ_REPROVADAS,@DESCRICAO,@DESCRICAO2,@MES)
                            SET
                            `Familia` = trim(@FAMILIA),
                            `Brand` = trim(@BRAND),
                            `QT_Lote` = trim(@QT_LOTE),
                            `QT_Amostra` = trim(@QT_AMOSTRA),
                            `maq_reprovadas` = trim(@MAQ_REPROVADAS),
                            `descricao` = trim(@DESCRICAO),
                            `descricao2` = trim(@DESCRICAO2),
                            `mes` = trim(@MES),
                            `week` = '$week'
                            ";
```

a variável `$week` é o nome do arquivo sem a extensão que eu joguei na variável a variável `$campos` é o  nome do arquivo com a extensão. o resto é as colunas que tem na tabela do banco e na planilha csv alguém sabe por esta dando esse problema.

Comment: Esse problema geralmente acontece quando você abre o CSV no excell pois o danado coloca essas aspas e não as mostra pra vc fazendo vc achar que elas não existem. Abre o arquivo em um editor de texto e veja se as aspas realmente não existem

Comment: coloquei no txt pegou aspas, eu encontrei eu maneira no mysql chamada ENCLOSED BY ' " ' mais no php esta dando erro de sintaxe por causa das aspas que delimita o load por exemplo:  $query =  "load data local infile ...";

Answer (score 2):

Faltou isso:

```
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

para escapar as aspas.

Veja a sintaxe no manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Ficando assim:

```
$sql = "
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/report/uploads/$campo'
       INTO TABLE reparo.oob
       character set 'utf8'
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
       IGNORE 1 LINES
       ...
";
```

**Notar as barras invertidas (`\`) para fazer o escape dos caracteres especiais.**

Uma outra solução é usar HEREDOC:

```
$sql = <<<FINAL
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/report/uploads/$campo'
                            INTO TABLE reparo.oob
                            character set 'utf8'
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                               OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
                            IGNORE 1 LINES;
                            ...
FINAL;
```